# How would I add a progress bar to display on form button click that shows the progress of form2 load

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have a Start form with a "View Records" button. On the Records Form Load event I have the loop that populates a datagridview on the Records Form. What I want to do is show a progress bar next to the "View Records" button on the Start form that shows the progress of the datagridview on the Records form when the user clicks the "View Records" button. Then, once the datagridview loop is successfully completed I want to bring up the Records form (but still leave Start form open as parent form, so the "View Record" form would be brought up by a ShowDialog). I have the simple code to show the progress bar on "View Records" button click. I'm reading around to find that maybe a background worker might be what I need, but I do not know how to work with it. Could someone help walk me through it and provide some code to help me along? Some info, the start form is called 'Start' and the View Records form is called 'Records.' The progress bar is name 'pb'. Thank you in advance to anyone who attempts to help!

Ok, here's the updated code with the error

```
Imports Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Public Class Start
Dim Records As New Records
Dim excel_app As Excel.Application
Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim exeDir As New IO.FileInfo(Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.FullName)
Dim xlPath = IO.Path.Combine(exeDir.DirectoryName, "Records.xlsx")

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    bw.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork



    ' Get the Excel application object.
    excel_app = New Excel.Application

    ' Make Excel visible (optional).
    excel_app.Visible = False

    ' Open the workbook.
    workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    sheet_name = "2013"

    sheet = excel_app.Worksheets("2013")

    Dim ColumnCount, RowCount, TotalCellCount As Long
    ColumnCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
    RowCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    Records.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = ColumnCount - 1
    Records.DataGridView1.RowCount = RowCount - 1
    Records.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True
    Records.DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = True
    TotalCellCount = Records.DataGridView1.ColumnCount * Records.DataGridView1.RowCount

    pb.Visible = True
    pb.Minimum = 0
    pb.Value = 0
    pb.Maximum = TotalCellCount

    Records.DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing
    Records.DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
    Records.DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = False
    Records.DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True


    Records.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

    'Loop through each column
    Dim cIndex As Integer = 0
    While cIndex < ColumnCount

        'Loop through and populate each row in column
        Dim rIndex As Integer = 0
        While rIndex < RowCount - 1
            If cIndex = 0 Then
                'Set row header titles
                Records.DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rIndex).HeaderCell.Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex).Value()

                Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex + 1).Value()
            End If
            If cIndex > 0 Then
                Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex + 1).Value()
            End If

            'Set column header title
            Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).HeaderText = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, cIndex + 1).Value

            'Change last cell (Result) color Red or Green to represent positive gain or negative loss
            If rIndex = RowCount - 2 Then
                If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value < 0 Then
                    Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                    Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
                End If
                If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value > 0 Then
                    Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
                    Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
                End If
                If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = 0 Then
                    Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = "Broke Even"
                End If

            End If

            'Update the progress bar after each cell is populated
            bw.ReportProgress((rIndex * cIndex) / TotalCellCount)

            rIndex = rIndex + 1

        End While

        'Format all cells in column as currency values
        Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"
        'Make column unsortable
        Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        'Resize all Row Headers so user can see Row Titles without resizing
        Records.DataGridView1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)

        cIndex = cIndex + 1
    End While

    Records.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()

End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
    pb.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub

Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Background Worker Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Else
        If e.Cancelled Then
            'worker was cancelled
        Else
            'worker completed, open form2 here
            pb.Visible = False
            Records.ShowDialog()
            If (Records.DialogResult) Then
                ' Close the workbook.
                workbook.Close()

                ' Close the Excel server.
                excel_app.Quit()
            End If

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Am I doing this right? And how do I fixed the error?

Comment: Where is this progress bar, Form1, 2 or some extra form? Are you sure where the delay is. Putting the code in form load may be your biggest issue. In general I'd show the form, and then call an explicit method to do the populate. I'd only look at threading, if get and process phase was slow and I'd do that before I showed the form. Or if I wanted to be asynchronous, i.e. keep form1 available for other actions, while the "form2" process was figuring out what to do. That would also be separating get and process from display.

Comment: Just to clarify if Form1 is unusble, and form2 can't be displayed yet, threading it and synchronising the UI is pointless complexity. You need to separate the concerns.

Comment: The progress bar is in Form 1, next to the "View Records" button and displays when the "View Records" button is clicked. I'm a little lost with what you said. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. Should I move the populate loop code outside of the form load event in the Records form? If so, how would I get the loop to start then?

Comment: Depends on where the delay is. Is it getting the data, say executing  a db query, processing it after you've got it, or simply displaying the data. Could be all three. Google VB.net background thread and progress bar, for the how, whether you should do it though is a different question. I wouldn't have the bar on form 1 though, if I was expecting form2 to be shown modally, unless I had a cancel button.

Comment: Another way. Do row and column headers in their own loop. Do the colouring in't own loop. In a separate loop for the main body, call DataGridView1.Update. Progress would be indicated by items displaying in the grid. Take the code out of formload and put it in formshow or activate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I would need that code spoon-fed to me. Could you help break it all apart and help me put things in the right spot/form,etc?

Comment: It's already there. Instead of checking if cIndex == 0 inside the loop. do that bit first, and start the loop from 1. After you've set the row up in the loop call the update method n the grid control, it will draw it on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a background worker on Form1 and then subscribe to its ProgressChanged event to update the progress bar. Then when the worker completes, you can pass that data to Form2 and open it.

Assuming you add a BackgroundWorker called bw to Form1

On the Button click event you need to start the worker by calling `bw.RunWorkerAsync`

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Setup()
  bw.RunWorkerAsync()
```

End Sub

```
Private Sub Setup()
' Get the Excel application object.
excel_app = New Excel.Application

' Make Excel visible (optional).
excel_app.Visible = False

' Open the workbook.
workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
sheet_name = "2013"

sheet = excel_app.Worksheets("2013")

Dim ColumnCount, RowCount, TotalCellCount As Long
ColumnCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
RowCount = sheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Records.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = ColumnCount - 1
Records.DataGridView1.RowCount = RowCount - 1
Records.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = True
Records.DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = True
TotalCellCount = Records.DataGridView1.ColumnCount * Records.DataGridView1.RowCount

pb.Visible = True
pb.Minimum = 0
pb.Value = 0
pb.Maximum = TotalCellCount

Records.DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing
Records.DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeColumns = False
Records.DataGridView1.AllowUserToResizeRows = False
Records.DataGridView1.ReadOnly = True


Records.DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells

End Sub
```

Then in the bw.DoWork event you would run the code to fetch the data. Create a form level variable so you can access it in the DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted Events

```
Dim f as New RecordForm

Private Sub bw_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bw.DoWork


'Loop through each column
Dim cIndex As Integer = 0
While cIndex < ColumnCount

    'Loop through and populate each row in column
    Dim rIndex As Integer = 0
    While rIndex < RowCount - 1
        If cIndex = 0 Then
            'Set row header titles
            Records.DataGridView1.Rows.Item(rIndex).HeaderCell.Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex).Value()

            Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex + 1).Value()
        End If
        If cIndex > 0 Then
            Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex + 1).Value()
        End If

        'Set column header title
        Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).HeaderText = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, cIndex + 1).Value

        'Change last cell (Result) color Red or Green to represent positive gain or negative loss
        If rIndex = RowCount - 2 Then
            If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value < 0 Then
                Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
            If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value > 0 Then
                Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.BackColor = Color.Green
                Records.DataGridView1.Item(cIndex, rIndex).Style.ForeColor = Color.White
            End If
            If Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = 0 Then
                Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = "Broke Even"
            End If

        End If

        'Update the progress bar after each cell is populated
        bw.ReportProgress((rIndex * cIndex) / TotalCellCount)

        rIndex = rIndex + 1

    End While

    'Format all cells in column as currency values
    Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c"
    'Make column unsortable
    Records.DataGridView1.Columns(cIndex).SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
    'Resize all Row Headers so user can see Row Titles without resizing
    Records.DataGridView1.AutoResizeRowHeadersWidth(DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.AutoSizeToAllHeaders)

    cIndex = cIndex + 1
End While

Records.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns()
End Sub

Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bw.ProgressChanged
  ProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

When the worker is finished it will fire its completed event.

```
Private Sub bw_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bw.RunWorkerCompleted
  If e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
    MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message, "Background Worker Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
  Else
    If e.Cancelled Then
      'worker was cancelled
    Else
      'worker finished. open Form2
      f.Show
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an InvalidOperationException with the following explanation "This BackgroundWorker states that it doesn't report progress. Modify WorkerReportsProgress to state that it does report progress." I added all the parts that you shared with me, but it's still returning the exception

Comment: How would I fetch the data? The datagridview is on the second form (Records form) and is populated in the load event of the second form

Comment: The exception is telling you what to do. Set the `WorkerReportsProgress` property to `True`. You can do this in the designer or the code.

Comment: I just found and fixed that, thank you! It works, but I want to make the progress bar show the progress of the loop that executes in the records form load event where it populates the dataviewgrid. How could I do this and have it progress with each cell as the loop fills them?

Comment: See my edits. Declare a form level variable of the records form so you can access its properties. When the worker completes you would call the show method

Comment: I would set the `ProgressBar.Maximum` property to the number of rows in the excel sheet. After you process each row you would set the `ProgressBar.Value += 1`

Comment: Ok, I did everything you told me. I took all the code I had in my Records form on form load event and put in in my Start form. I updated the code above. Am I doing this right? I'm getting an InvalidOperationException with the explanation "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Start' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." and it's pointing to my progress bar named 'pb'

Comment: I updated my answer with your code. I forgot you were accessing UI controls (the progress bar) from another thread. Basically you need to set those properties before running the worker.

Comment: I have it halfway running, where the progress bar begins filling and when it gets to this line in my loop "Records.DataGridView1.Rows(rIndex).Cells(cIndex).Value = sheet.Range("A1").Offset(rIndex + 1, cIndex + 1).Value()" it gives the error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"                         Do you think there's a way to redo my loop so it's not so complicated or is there an easy fix for the error? I already tried removing the +1 on either side and it didn't help

Comment: I believe I got it now, thank you for all your help. I really appreciate you taking the time and helping me.